# Mediaserver for XBOX360

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, xbox360, upnp

as i want to do some programming in my freetime (yeah i need another project), i thought of a mediaServer for my xbox360 (like tversity or ps3 mediaServer).
what do i want to stream?

- normal movie content (which could be streamed via mediaExtender)
- mkv and vob (rips of my dvd collection)
- maybe music and pictures

atm i have no clue which requirements i need to meet to get started, like:

- how does streaming to a xbox360 work?
- which protocols do i need?
- how can i communicate with the 360?
- how can i add pictures of a movie to the playlist?
- how can i transcode a movie source?
- are there any good tuts for my mission?
- and so on ...

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ushare](http://ushare.geexbox.org/), which is an open source UPnP server (one of the media protocols that works with Xbox 360).

Comment: interesting project - but i'm not into too deep with c and linux :) sry ...

Comment: I'm not saying contribute to or copy it, but you could look at that for information about UPnP and maybe a basic understanding about what you are getting into.

Comment: :) that was what i tried to say ...